# BITXOR in Excel producing unexpected value

Tags: excel

I get the following results with Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.6701.1011) 64-bit:

```
=BITXOR(10,1111)
```

produces:

```
1117
```

I expected `1101`.

However `=BITXOR(10,111)` produces `101` which is what I expected.

Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bitxor()` accepts as arguments, and returns, decimal numbers. You can convert your arguments to decimal, and the result to binary like this:

```
=DEC2BIN(BITXOR(BIN2DEC(10),BIN2DEC(1111)))
```